Wifi not working on Fedora 40
I am using a lenovo ideapad 15irh laptop with a replaced rtl8822ce network card. I am using windows 10 as my secondary system, everything works fine there. On Fedora, after installing it, networks were detected but connection failed. Now, after manipulating the drivers via modprobe, the wifi module does not show up on the system at all.
lspci -k:
07:00.0 Network controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8822CE 802.11ac PCIe Wireless Network Adapter    
  Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device 85f7    
  Kernel modules: rtl88x2ce
08:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. TL8111/8168/8211/8411 PCIExpress Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev10)   
  Subsystem: Lenovo Device 38cf     
  Kernel driver in use: r8169   
  Kernel modules: r8169

journalctl -f -u NetworkManager.service
июн 04 16:50:05 fedora NetworkManager[1126]: <info>  [1717509005.7430] dhcp4 (enp0s20f0u3): activation: beginning transaction (timeout in 45 seconds)
июн 04 16:50:07 fedora NetworkManager[1126]: <info>  [1717509007.7500] dhcp4 (enp0s20f0u3): state changed new lease, address=192.168.193.153, acd pending
июн 04 16:50:07 fedora NetworkManager[1126]: <info>  [1717509007.9007] dhcp4 (enp0s20f0u3): state changed new lease, address=192.168.193.153
июн 04 16:50:07 fedora NetworkManager[1126]: <info>  [1717509007.9011] policy: set 'Проводное подключение 2' (enp0s20f0u3) as default for IPv4 routing and DNS
июн 04 16:50:07 fedora NetworkManager[1126]: <info>  [1717509007.9132] device (enp0s20f0u3): state change: ip-config -> ip-check (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
июн 04 16:50:07 fedora NetworkManager[1126]: <info>  [1717509007.9154] device (enp0s20f0u3): state change: ip-check -> secondaries (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
июн 04 16:50:07 fedora NetworkManager[1126]: <info>  [1717509007.9156] device (enp0s20f0u3): state change: secondaries -> activated (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
июн 04 16:50:07 fedora NetworkManager[1126]: <info>  [1717509007.9160] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_SITE
июн 04 16:50:07 fedora NetworkManager[1126]: <info>  [1717509007.9163] device (enp0s20f0u3): Activation: successful, device activated.
июн 04 16:50:08 fedora NetworkManager[1126]: <info>  [1717509008.0159] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_GLOBAL

(im used my phone as hotspot)
I can provide more information if it need...

I have no idea about what you did with modprobe, but that shouldn't be persistent, so restarting the computer should restore normal config. Maybe you'll get some clues by running journalctl -f -u NetworkManager.service. Also, it may be a good idea to boot with a live image of Fedora on a USB stick, so that you can test things like adding a driver, without breaking your current Fedora install.

updated, i will try boot in live

Also from your posted output, as per Kate, that snippet seems to indicate you're connected with an IP address of 192.168.193.153, which is a valid LAN IP Address
